# mean, std and counts in one record

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, aggregation

I have data that looks like this:

```
id  res     res_q
1   12.9    normal
2   11.5    low
3   13.2    normal
4    9.7    low
5   12.0    low
6   15.5    normal
7   13.5    normal
8   13.3    normal
9   13.5    normal
10  13.1    normal
11  13.4    normal
12  12.9    normal
13  11.8    low
14  11.9    low
15  12.8    normal
16  13.1    normal
17  12.2    normal
18  11.9    low
19  12.5    normal
20  16.5    normal
```

res_q can take the values 'low', 'normal' and 'high'.

I want to aggregate it so in one record I will have both the mean and std of res, and the counts of low, normal and high, all in one record, like this

```
mean      sd    low normal  high
12.9    1.41      6     14     0
```

Off course I can do it by first aggregating the mean and std using AVG and STDEV, and then using COUNT to get the low/normal/high counts, like this:

```
SELECT AVG(res) AS mean, 
       STD(res) AS sd,
       (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM temp1 WHERE res_q='low') AS low,
       (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM temp1 WHERE res_q='normal') AS normal,
       (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM temp1 WHERE res_q='high') AS high
FROM temp1
```

But, is there a more efficient way to do it?

One possibility I can think of is first to get the mean and the sd using AVG and STDEV, then get the counts using GROUP BY and then add the counts using UPDATE. Is this really more efficient? Anything else?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you for your important comment. Unfortunately, I am not quite sure what is the name of my DBMS product. All I can say is that I use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 14.0.17199.0 (got it from help>about)

Answer (score 3):

Use conditional aggregation

```
SELECT AVG(res) AS mean, 
       STD(res) AS sd,
       count(case when res_q='low' then 1 end) AS low
       count(case when res_q='normal' then 1 end) AS normal,
       count(case when res_q='high' then 1 end) AS high
FROM temp1
```